# "Benediction" vs. "blessing"

Tags: differences, nouns

Is there a difference in meaning between the words *benediction* and *blessing*? Why would one be used over the other?

Comment: I suggest to explain which part of the definitions of these words in dictionaries and/or wiki you found unclear, otherwise this might be seen as a general reference question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally *bless* was derived from the Germanic word *bletsian* (meaning *to sanctify with blood*) and was used to translate the Latin *benedicere* (literally *to speak well of*).

So there was little earlier difference in meaning.  But *bless* was far more productive and widened its meaning, while *benediction* became largely restricted to a short invocation in a religious service, sometimes now described as *the blessing*.

Answer (score 4):

*Benediction* has a religious tone to it; at the end of a church service, there is often a *benediction*. Blessing is less religious:

> My son told me he was leaving home, and after a few tears, I gave him my blessing, and he was off.

This doesn't sound as religious as *benediction*. So use *benediction* when speaking in religious terms, and *blessing* when you aren't.